# Behavior of Cell.Offset versus ActiveCell.Offset in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a For loop & a For Each loop in VBA, where I am searching for a string within the content of each cell in the loop using Offset:

Using For Each:

```
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("M2:M" & Lastrow)

countrows = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For Each Cell In Myrange 
    If strPattern <> "" Then
    If Cell.Offset(0, 31) <> "Fizz" Then
        strInput = Cell.Value
```

Using For:

```
countrows = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To countrows
    Range("AK" & i).Select
    check_value = ActiveCell
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) <> "Buzz" Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
```

In the bottom example, I must use ActiveCell.Offset. Using Cell.Offset or even Cell.Offset.Value throws an "Object Required" error.

Why is this the case?

Comment: My guess would be because in the `For` loop you're using "select", where as in the `For each` you're specifically referencing the cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the bottom example you haven't defined what `Cell` is so VBA has no clue as to what you're trying to do. `Cell` isn't a special word - it is a variable in the top example

A better way to write your bottom statement would be to use a `With` instead of the `ActiveCell` and `Select`

```
countrows = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To countrows
    With Range("AK" & i)
        check_value = .Value2
        If .Offset(0, 7) <> "Buzz" Then
            .EntireRow.Copy
        End If
    End With
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

In first loop Cell is a Range object.
In second one Cell is `Nothing`, you must assign a Range object to it i.e.:

```
Set Cell = Range("AK" & i)
```

Btw, do you declare your variables?